# How do I group T-SQL set by a flag bigint column

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, bitwise-operators

I'm working on a project where efficiency of the search functionality is critical.

I have several flag columns (like enum flags in c#). Searching on this data is super fast (3 milliseconds round trip) but I've come-a-cropper now I have to perform group counts.

So, I have an item 'A' that contains Red (1), White (8) and blue (64) so the 'Colours' column holds the number 73.

To search I can search for items with red with this

```
Declare @colour int
set @colour = 1

Select * 
From Items  
Where (Colour & @colour) > 0
```

That works great. Now I have to group it (also super fast)

So if I have 8 items in total, 5 contain red, 3 contain white and 7 contain blue the results would look like:

```
Colour      Qty
------------------
1           5
8           3
64          7 ( I don't have to worry about the name )
```

So: Is there any way I can take the number 73 and bitwise split it into groups?

(Part 2: How do I translate that into Linq to SQL?)

Any advise would be appreciated

Thanks ^_^

Comment: You have a enumeration.  In SQL Server you can use CHECK CONSTRANT : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017.            enum Color
            {
                RED = 1,
                WHITE = 8,
                BLUE = 64
            }

Comment: Thanks for looking @jdweng, but I think I found an answer now ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I think I've worked out the best solution:

I tried a view with a cte:

```
with cte as (
  select cast(1 as bigint) as flag, 1 pow
  union all
  select POWER(cast(2 as bigint),pow), pow + 1
  from cte
  where flag < POWER(cast(2 as bigint),62)
)
, cte2 as (
  select flag from cte
  union select -9223372036854775808
)
```

but that was too slow so now I have made it into a static table.  I join with a bitwise '&':

```
select Flag, Count(*)
From FlagValues fv 
inner join Items i on (fv.Flag & i.Colour)
```

Much faster ^_^